# I'm getting name not defined while calling it in the testcase, I'm using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

```
def test_execute_partner_action(param):
    '''
    sample_test
    '''
    node_obj = Node.find()
    partner_obj = Node.find(node=node_obj.get_partner())
    _execute_partner_action(node_obj, partner_obj, client_obj, server_obj)

def _execute_partner_action(partner, reboot_wait, client_obj, server_obj, rdma_direction=['server', 'client'], rdma_partner_action=None):
    LOG.step('this is inside def') 
    client_obj = kwargs['client_obj']
    rdma_direction = kwargs['rdma_direction']
    rdma_partner_action = kwargs['rdma_partner_action']
    server_obj = kwargs['server_obj']
```

**Error message:** `NameError: name 'client_obj' is not defined`

I'm new to python, want to make it working to complete my script, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see where you set `client_obj` to anything.

Comment: Try to add `global client_obj` at the start of your function

Comment: @CofeDrink68 That's only useful if you need to *assign* to the global. It doesn't make the name visible if it isn't already.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `kwargs` - these are keyword arguments. All these assignments from `kwargs` do not make sense, you can just use the arguments directly.